# jQuery Code runs no matter what

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have this jQuery code which is only suppose to show an alert for a new message when a record is found within the Database.

**index.html (jQuery code)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        $.post("messagecheck.php", { countOld: count },
        function(data){
            if(data == 0) {
                alert("No New Messages");
                return;
         } else {
                count = data; // This will change the count for each run, you could store this in div with .data() ...
                alert("New Message!");
                return;        
         }
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

**messagecheck.php**

```
<?php

    if($uid == 0) {
        die(); // not logged in
    } else {
        $sql = 'SELECT messagecount FROM Users WHERE uid = $uid AND messagecount >= 1';
        $result = mysql_query($sql);         
        if(!$result) {
            // Kill SQL and return error
        } else {
            // We will be sending an Old Count via POST
            $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            echo $numRows;
            if( $numRows == $_POST['countOld']) {
                // No change
                echo 'No change: 0';    
            } else 
                echo $numRows;
        }
    }

?>
```

Even if the $uid is 0 (user is not logged in) the alert for New Message! shows.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's your conditional:

```
if(data == 0) {
```

And here's what your AJAX call returns:

```
echo 'No change: 0';
```

The conditional evaluates to `false` because `'No change: 0'` doesn't equal `0`.

Comment: I have changed this now but still the same problem, I've even removed the whole PHP code before and the New Message! alert still shows.

Comment: Try doing a `console.log(data)` to see what is being returned.

Comment: @user1626410: It looks like you also have a server-side code path which returns no value at all.  Inspect the actual values being returned by your server-side code and use those actual values in your client-side conditional.  Currently they don't match.

Answer (score 4):

You have a lot of logic problems.

1. If the user ID is 0 (not logged in) then you kill the PHP script; nothing is returned. This is *not* the same as `false`, it will evaluate as `''` and `'' !== 0`.
2. If the SQL statement fails, same problem.

You need to re-factor your PHP script to either return a consistent result no matter what. Something like this:

```
<?php
$new_messages = false;

if ($uid > 0) {
    $sql = 'SELECT messagecount FROM Users WHERE uid = ? AND messagecount >= 1';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($uid));
    $row = $stmt->fetchObject();

    if (is_object($row) && intval($row->messagecount) !== intval($_POST['countOld'])) {
        $new_messages = true;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');

print json_encode(array(
    'new_messages' => $new_messages
));
```

This will return a boolean (`true` or `false`) value no matter what, which you can then test against in your JavaScript:

```
$.post('messagecheck.php', { countOld: count }, function(result) {
    if (result && result.new_messages) {
        if (result.new_messages === true) {
            alert('You have a new message.');
        }
    }
});
```

Also, don’t use `mysql_` functions, they’re deprecated as per the warning on the PHP.net manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: When I try this i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRINT in messagecheck.php on line 43

Comment: Missing ; on the end of header() but now i get this Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at functions.php:61) functions.php is included at the top

Comment: The error message is telling you problem: somewhere in **functions.php** you’ve got code that sends output, whether it’s a `print()` statement or `echo()` statement or something of that ilk.

Answer (score 2):

If the `$uid` is `0` then there will be no data sent from the server. `data` will be emtpy, so the `data == 0` will evaluate to false. Try this:

```
if (!data) {
    alert("No New Messages");
    return;
} else {
    count = data;
    alert("New Message!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Try `console.log(data);` or `alert(data);` as the very first command in the callback function, to see what is actually returned from the server. I'm not sure how `die()` works and whether it produces any output or not.

Comment: I tried running through firebug and I get 403 Forbidden on messagecheck.php POST

Comment: Well there you go... seems like there's a server configuration rather than a code issue. There are some logic flaws as @MartinBean correctly said, but first you need to fix the issue with the server config to allow you to make POST requests to your script.

Answer (score 1):

**There are basically six things that might be the issue - that I can think of:**

- In PHP you're echoing out 'No change: 0'.
- You're using `die();` as a return-value
- You're echoing out same number twice.
- `$numRows` and/or `$_POST['countOld']` aren't returning expected
  values
- In jQuery you're using ==. This operator evaluates a value
- You're executing ajax-code once a second and jQuery is doing async -
  calls

**Change part of PHP:**

```
   } else {
        // We will be sending an Old Count via POST
        $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo $numRows;
        if( $numRows == $_POST['countOld']) {
            // No change
            echo 'No change: 0';    
        } else 
            echo $numRows;
    }
```

to:

```
   } else {
        // We will be sending an Old Count via POST
        $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        //Before you hade echo $numRows. This would make numRows echo out twice
        //because it's echoed it down below also
        if( $numRows == $_POST['countOld']) {
            // No change
            echo 0; //Echo out 0.    
        } else 
            echo $numRows;
    }
```

**Why?** Because echo 'No change: 0'; evaulates to false and no the value 0.

in jQuery (javascript) - ***use typeof to check the actual value***, like this:

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            $.post("messagecheck.php", { countOld: count },
            function(data){
                if(typeof data == 0) {
                    alert("No New Messages");
                    return;
             } else {
                    count = data; // This will change the count for each run, you could store this in div with .data() ...
                    alert("New Message!");
                    return;        
             }
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
```

***Log/Inspect*** values of $numRows and $_POST['countOld'] and see if you'e getting what you're expecting.

You're executing ajax-code once a second and jQuery is doing async calls. If doing eveything above and all seems fine, ***I would change interval to a larger number*** just to be sure so the calls itself aren't screwing things up. I'm not sure you have to check as often as a second?

***Instead of using*** `die()` when userid = 0, ***just echo out 0*** with `echo '0';`. (then the script would not fail)

And of course - ***don't use mysql_* - functions*** if you absolutely don't have to, because they're deprecated. And in you're case, it's open to sql-injections etc, but that is another issue.